# How can I pass form input value inside PHP function properly in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I'm trying to create a woocommerce custom filter, in which I can filter shop page by my custom meta keys, which already has been created.
So I created a `form` before shop loop:

```
function _themename_woocommerce_custom_filter() {
    if( isset($_GET['submit']) ) {
        $year_min = esc_attr($_GET['year_min']);
        $year_max = esc_attr($_GET['year_max']);
    }

    ?>
        <form id="custom-filter" class="custom-filter" action="" method="get">
            <input id="number_field_year_min" type="number" name="year_min" value="<?php echo $year_min; ?>" />
            <input id="number_field_year_max" type="number" name="year_max" value="<?php echo $year_max; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search">
        </form>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', '_themename_woocommerce_custom_filter', 3 );
```

So now I have two inputs and I want to get this values and pass inside this function, which is filtering my shop page product by meta key:

```
function show_only_products_with_specific_metakey( $meta_query, $query ) {
    $year_min = 1950;
    $year_max = 2020;

    if( ! is_shop() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_number_field_year',
        'value'   => array($year_min, $year_max),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    );
    return $meta_query;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'show_only_products_with_specific_metakey', 10, 2 );
```

What I need is take my values from form after clicking submit button and pass it inside my function and change static values 1950 and 2020 to dynamic.

Also I tried to use cookies like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  const cookieMin = $("#number_field_year_min").val();
  createCookie("year_min_value", cookieMin, "10");
});

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
  var expires;
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  }
  else {
    expires = "";
  }
  document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

and then pass it inside my function and change variable value:

```
$year_min = $_COOKIE['year_min_value'];
```

it's actually working, but only after second click on submit button and I'm not sure is it good practice to make like this.

I tried my best to explain, sorry for my English. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @7uc1f3r I edited my question, thanks, and previous one wasn't duplicated, there was a big difference.

Comment: @7ucf1f3r no way) let this one be a new question. Thanks.